# Running program in background

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, background

I've a mini project I have to do in "Information System Security" subject, the idea is I have to run a program in background when the user is browsing the net and perform some actions.
I've made some search and I think i may need to write a windows service program. Is that correct? or what should I do to make my program run in background? 
please any help.
Thanks.

Comment: What sort of activity it has to perform and what would be its frequency?

Comment: Actually It must catch what the user write when browsing specific website, and get mouse position and take a screen shot.

Comment: @Ruba that sounds more like a spyware.

Comment: I know, it's "Information System Security" subject, so we need to know how they work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a Winforms application, delete the form, and put your code in the Main() method in Program.cs. Keep it alive as long as you need, and run whatever background tasks you need too.

Answer (score 1):

To make your program run in background you can use event `Shown` of your form.

put this into Shown event:

```
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write a service-Program you can hide your program-windows after the program started with

```
ShowWindow(HWND,int);
```

In order to get the Window-Handler to your own Window, you can use for example

```
HWND explorer=::FindWindow(NULL,"explorer.exe");
```

or

```
HWND h = ::GetTopWindow(0);
while ( h )
{    if(IsWindowVisible(h)==1 && /*check if it's your Window*/)
     {   ShowWindow(h,0);//will hide Window
         break;
     }
     h = ::GetNextWindow( h , GW_HWNDNEXT);
}
```

You will have to

```
#include <winuser.h>
```

to use this functions

Comment: 1) This doesn't work (directly) with C#. 2) A C# application program can run without a window.